# Infer output array type from type argument of input items

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm currently writing typings for a function that takes in an array of `Clazz<U>` objects, and returns an array of `U`. `U` isn't always identical between all the arguments.

**Is it possible to set the return type to an array of all the values of `U`?**

I've tried a variety of things including various usages of `keyof` and `typeof`, but simply doing so within the typings doesn't seem to give any results. The `U`-typed value of each `Clazz` item is accessed via a call to `(instanceof Clazz).value`.

Example function: (actual code in context [on GitHub](https://github.com/pulse-framework/pulse/blob/083c0699cbabca9f736bc923735fe0969b17a4c3/lib/integrations/react.integration.ts#L97-L154))

```
function example(input: Array<Clazz<U>>): Array<U> {
    const out = [];
    
    for(const item of input) {
        out.push(item.value); // where item.value instanceof U === true
    }
    
    return out;
}
```

Ideal outcomes:

```
// if this is possible it would be fantastic!
example([new Clazz('this is a string'), new Clazz(500)]); // output type: [string, number]

// a union is acceptable!
example([new Clazz('this is a string'), new Clazz(500)]); // output type: Array<string | number>
```

Comment: So `T` is a class?  That's a weird class name (usually `T` is used as a type parameter).  This isn't quite a [mcve] without a definition of `T` (external links don't count) but I guess it's just something with a `value` property.

Comment: @jcalz I've updated the question to clarify this for any future readers :) Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't consider that when writing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to use this implementation for `T`... and I'm not going to call it `T` because that name is usually used for generic type parameters.  I'll call it, uh, `Tee` instead:

```
class Tee<U> {
    constructor(public value: U) { }
}
```

Here's how I'd write `example()`:

```
function example<X extends Array<Tee<any>>>(input: X | []) {
    const out = [] as any as { [K in keyof X]: X[K] extends Tee<infer U> ? U : never };

    for (const item of input) {
        out.push(item.value); 
    }

    return out;
}
```

There are a few things going on there.  One is that `example` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function, whose generic type parameter `X` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be an array of some `Tee`-like thing (`Tee<any>`).  Let's imagine that the `input` parameter is of type `X` (I'll explain `X | []` below).  Then the output type is what we've asserted `out` to be:

```
{ [K in keyof X]: X[K] extends Tee<infer U> ? U : never }
```

That is [mapping the array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) `X` to another array type, where we unwrap `Tee<U>` to `U` for each element, using [conditional type inferences](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types).  That's the type manipulation you're looking for.

There's not really any chance the compiler would be able to figure out that you're doing that type manipulation just by examining the implementation of `example()`, which is why I had to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell it that's what `out` will be.

The last bit to explain is the `| []` in the `input` type.  This is just a hint so that the compiler will try to interpret an array literal passed in for `input` as a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) type instead of as an unordered array, as explained in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179#issuecomment-422606990) of [microsoft/TypeScript#27179](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179), a GitHub issue asking for a way to prefer tuples over unordered arrays.  Without the `| []` you'd tend to get an unordered array (which I guess you're fine with, but is not necessary).

Enough explanation, let's test it:

```
example([new Tee('this is a string'), new Tee(500)]); // [string, number]
```

Looks good!  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.0.2#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCm8A8BVAfNA3gKGn6wA9gHYQAuATgK7BmEUAUADlQEYgCWw0AbmCFXgAuaCgCUWaAF9sM7ADMqxWhxLR4ADzABbJiGQANdRrLxiAExgBBChTABPJAmRhi9tB4YdiLMiKMAPtAA2gC6Ejj4BCTk0IRUZNAAvCGh0JDpbukwmCEA0tDe0ADW8PaE8tAGof7BeWmaphYwzkje8vAUohgA-KLQIsTwPJ3SANzYuPjy9NAMRKSJHKbacZXevhFTUXjxZAB0LBAAFl4r+3wC8GJj0NvSd-cU8GRUFMRxCRNyAPQ-hZUyMcODAQdAmIQoBx2PBCokAO7xEDmaCsWHyVxkSBkLgAQmwmh0engDGCQ3hcEQDAA5ECwWCwNByBRvABzaliAA00HJlJJAFYAAyCsThW5-T5kXzQMj2JjCELMtnc4hUbRoiihSZAA)